# gulp-markdown-docs yaml parsing error

Tags: gulp, markdown

When trying to use the gulp-markdown-docs plugin with gulp, I get the following error: `end of the stream or a document separator is expected at line ..., column ...` for each file that I want to parse.

In the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-markdown-docs) they say to make a header of the type:

```
---
label: Nav Label
categoryLabel: 
categoryRank: 

# Your Content
...
```

in order for the yaml parsing to work (i'm skipping some because I don't need them). I don't know yaml, but I've tried with some separator just after categoryRank and I got the same error.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an error in the docs, should be:

```
---
label: Nav Label
categoryLabel: 
categoryRank: 
...

# Your Content
```

Comment: tried it too and it did not work..., but I found the string I piped into gulp-markdown-docs had newline characters written as `\r\n`, so I simply replaced globally each \r\n with \n and it worked well.

Comment: There is indeed an error in the docs though, since the header should end with --- instead of ... because of how yaml is parsing and detects a header.